# What are the roots of unity quadratic integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The article of [Roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Relation_to_integer_rings) in wikipedia implies that the following roots of unity are quadratic numbers:
$$
\{\pm 1\}, \{\pm 1,\pm i\}, \{\pm 1,\pm \zeta,\pm \zeta^2\}.
$$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.

I'm wondering if this list is complete but I had no idea until I searched MSE, which returns the following question:

[Roots of unity in quartic fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253346/9464)

The answer seems to be yes since the OP of that question says that this is a well known fact. 
But I have no experience in algebraic number theory at all.

Can some one guide me to some references (or give a proof?) about this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. The cyclotomic field $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of $x^n-1$. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ which has degree $\varphi(n)$, so the field extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ has degree $\varphi(n)$. If $\zeta$ is also a quadratic integer then $\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ has degree $\le2$ and the only naturals $n$ for which $\varphi(n)\le2$ are $n=1,2,3,4,6$.